# Eclipse CDT + clang on Windows: install for "dummies"

Tags: eclipse-cdt, clang

I am running WinXP. I have Eclipse Indigo. I installed http://code.google.com/p/llvm4eclipsecdt/ but it appears that it's not configured correctly. I'd like to use the MinGW variant.

Is there an install guide that gives *all* the steps for installing correctly on a "fresh" Windows PC? Including the steps to install mingw properly -- I had an old version from 2010 but can't seem to get everything to work together -- and point the Eclipse CDT plugin to the right paths for binaries/includes/libraries/etc.

Answer (score 0):

by default it is configured for visual studio, but in case if you want to use it over migwin ...  [check thislink](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build)

take into account point (6) in section Building Clang and Working with the Code
On Unix-like Systems, you will be required to set right include paths .... and lib path

Comment: I have to build clang myself?!

Comment: might be someone else is providing precompiled binaries ? though building yourself is not that hard, thanks to cmake... give a try !!

Comment: no thank you, the instructions for clang on windows only talk about Visual Studio. there are millions of Windows PCs out there -- surely someone has prebuilt working clang binaries for it. sigh.

Comment: sure, but keep in mind.. the include path's !! ... they are hard coded.

Comment: check the link I mentioned above, the default includes paths for c and cpp headers are hard-coded in clang for various platform..